# Load Balancing a java application running in a cluster

Tags: java, load-balancing

I have multiple vms running all of the modules in the project. Each request created by the user has to be processed by all modules, but needs to be done only once. So if VM1 picks up a request then module1 can process the request partially, next VM1 or VM2 or any other VM in cluster can pick up and process for module2. And so on.

Since each VM is of limited capacity i would like to use a load balancer for allocating work among individual VM's.

Are there load balancers(open source for java) available which can solve this  or do i need to implement it using several load balancing algos(round robin,weighted etc) for solving my requirement?

Edit 1:

Each module is a java class which is independent in itself but needs previous modules to be done before its started.Each Vm is listening to a message bus. As and when a message appears in the bus any of the vm can pick up this and start working on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/) (TCP/HTTP loadbalancer ) which is open source, feature rich and quite widely used. Apart from good documentation you can find lots of information available.

Comment: Its not a web application which process http request. So this may not help

Comment: Ok, then what is the mode of communication or message passing.

Comment: Each Vm is listening to a message bus. As and when a message appears in the bus any of the vm can pick up this and start working on it.

Comment: So you already have a queue ( in form of message bus), if you add another vm as listening to this queue will this not load balance , something similar to multiple consumers listening to a message broker queue act as load balance since anyone can pick the message. You may though need something like consumer group so that messages are delieved to a vm's in a group only and to not all vm.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the exact semantics of the problem you're trying to parallelize, you might get good results by chunking your problem into "work packets" of some size and keeping them in a central queue. Then, just have each VM poll a packet from said queue as soon as it finished the previous packet. This is called self-scheduling.

Comment: Sounds like what i need. Can you point me at some material where this architecture is used?

Comment: I don't know of any generic solutions implementing this approach, sorry. The principle is usually simple enough to roll a custom solution though.

Comment: Also, depending on your problem and its scale, having such a centralized queue can become a bottleneck